# remove element from array compared to the second array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Hello guys I have two arrays: array1 and array2. It's a little bit complicated to explain the problem

```
var array1 = [39, "*", 62, "*", "*", 33.09,"*",56];
var array2 = [55, 6, 28, 32, 66, 58,15,56];
```

I want to have a array3 which compares the index in array1 and array2 and send the result to array 3
so my array3 should look like this

```
var array3 = [55,28,58,56]
```

I did try many solution but I was unsuccessful. Thanks for your help , and sorry for my newbie question - I am trying to learn.

Comment: have you looked into reducers?

Comment: Post the code that got you the closest to what you want. We can help you fix it.

Comment: _i did try many solution but i was unsseccessful_ So show your attempts.

Comment: what exactly do you compare? I cant get the algorithmus behind your provided solution.

Comment: ok sorry for posting this newbie question

Comment: i tried to remove one element at time from the second array like this array2[1] = "" but it didnt work and also the value of "*" could be anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you dont need to apologie for been a newbie , we all were newbie at some point in our career and we still learn new thing everyday

Second you need to use filter on the second array and return a new array based on the index that you did filterd

```js
var array1 = [39, "*", 62, "*", "*", 33.09,"*",56];
var array2 = [55, 6, 28, 32, 66, 58,15,56];


var result = array2.filter(function(x, i) {
  return array1[i] !== '*';
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and sorry

Answer (score 2):

You could check the first array and return from the second only items at the same index without a star.

```js
var array1 = [39, "*", 62, "*", "*", 33.09, "*", 56],
    array2 = [55, 6, 28, 32, 66, 58, 15, 56],
    result = array2.filter((a, i) => array1[i] !== '*');
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and sorry

Answer (score 2):

You can filter element of second array using `.filter()` like this:

```js
let a1 = [39, "*", 62, "*", "*", 33.09, "*", 56],
    a2 = [55, 6, 28, 32, 66, 58, 15, 56],
    skipElem = "*";

let result = a2.filter((_, i) => a1[i] !== skipElem);

console.log(result);
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Thank you for your time and sorry

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter`

```
var array3 = array2.filter( (s, i) => array1[i] != "*")
```

**Demo**

```js
var array1 = [39, "*", 62, "*", "*", 33.09,"*",56];
var array2 = [55, 6, 28, 32, 66, 58,15,56];
var array3 = array2.filter( (s, i) => array1[i] != "*");
console.log(array3);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and sorry

Comment: @Reactivelance sorry for what?

Comment: too many people put -5 on my question so it mean i am doing something wrong , but i am just trying to learn

Comment: I guess negative votes are for only showing the requirement and not your own attempt at solving the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array1 = [39, "*", 62, "*", "*", 33.09,"*",56];
var array2 = [55, 6, 28, 32, 66, 58,15,56];
var array3 = [];

for(var index=0;index< array1.length ;index++){
 if(array1[index] !== "*") {
   array3.push(array2[index]);
  }
}
console.log(array3);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and sorry